# Why does isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata return yes, even though a mapping model is used?

Tags: objective-c, core-data-migration

I am working on an app that uses the following method to determine if a Core Data migration is needed:

```
- (BOOL)isMigrationNeeded {
    BOOL isMigrationNeeded = NO;
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [self sourceMetadata:&error];
    if (sourceMetadata != nil) {
        NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel = [self managedObjectModel];
        isMigrationNeeded = ![destinationModel isConfiguration:nil
                                   compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];
    }

    return isMigrationNeeded;
}
```

In the latest version of the database, an attribute was added that requires a mapping model to set its value.  The value for the attribute is set properly, even though isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata returns YES.  As a result, the code which applies the mapping model is never called.

Is Core Data somehow applying the mapping model automatically?

This all works fine when the database is being migrated from the latest version.  But I tested migration from an older version of the database and it failed to set the new attribute's value.

I wanted to try a recursive Core Data migration approach I found in a tutorial, but it will not do anything if isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata returns YES.

I will gladly supply any necessary additional info.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug elsewhere in my code that overwrote the old version of the model with the new version of the model before isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata was called.

So isConfig... correctly returned yes.

My Bad!!!